# FATAL EXCEPTION: main ndroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, java

В программе необходимо подключиться к базе данных, решил сделать это через Json. Однако во время запуска выдает:

```
1259-1259/com.example.valera.homeweatherstation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.valera.homeweatherstation.parser.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:53)
            at com.example.valera.homeweatherstation.MySqlReader.AllProductsActivity$GetDataFromMySQL$1.run(AllProductsActivity.java:60)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Сам код (сделан через AsyncTask, в манифесте `<uses-permission android:name="android. permission.INTERNET"/>` прописано):

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView t_inside_text;    
    TextView t_outside_text;    
    TextView Pressure_text;    
    TextView Humidity_text;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static String url_get_data = "<ТУТ IP>";

    private static final String Success = "success";
    private static final String Data = "data";
    private static final String t_inside = "t_inside";
    private static final String t_outside = "t_outside";
    private static final String Pressure = "Pressure";
    private static final String Humidity = "Humidity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new GetDataFromMySQL().execute();
    }
    class GetDataFromMySQL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int success;
                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_data, "GET", params);

                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    success = json.getInt(Success);
                    if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(Data);

                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        t_inside_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_inside);
                        t_outside_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_outside);
                        Pressure_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Pressure);
                        Humidity_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Humidity);

                        t_inside_text.setText(product.getString(t_inside) + " °C");
                        t_outside_text.setText(product.getString(t_outside) + " °C");
                        Pressure_text.setText(product.getString(Pressure) + " мм.рт.столба");
                        Humidity_text.setText(product.getString(Humidity) + " %");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    }
}
```

И JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {

            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // возвращаем JSON строку
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

Comment: @Dumpling, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

*(зевая)*, у вас `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Удалите работу с сетью из основного потока.

```
class GetDataFromMySQL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        ...
        //создание сетевого подключения и получение инфы по сети
        }
```

Такого я ещё не видел...

```
com.example.valera  - забавно.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в AsyncTask выполняете код на главном потоке. ЗАЧЕМ??? Что это за ужасный велосипед из костылей?  
Вы используете AsyncTask, что бы вынести работу с сетью из главного потока, но внутри используете runOnUiThread что бы выполнить код на главном потоке. Это как в мультике про Чебурашку и Гену. "Гена, давай я понесу сумки, а ты понесешь меня".